# Firefox app link with website and Android app

Tags: java, android, firefox, web, applinks

I was browsing the stack overflow site on my phone (Android) using Firefox with the stack overflow app installed on my phone.

Firefox had an Android icon at the toolbar allowing me to directly use the stack overflow app.

Here is an image of that button:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I do that with my website and my app?

Comment: The http header includes a user-agent, which will describe the "requester's" device; you can then determine if it's a phone or not. Since you tagged java, I guess your site is written in JSP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968800/how-do-you-check-the-browsers-user-agent-in-a-jsp-page-using-jstl-el

Comment: On second thought, I see what you want to achieve now. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508783/firefox-for-android-native-app-icon-address-bar